# Gerar XML indentado através do PHP

Tags: php, xml

Olá, bom dia.

Estou gerando xml com php, mas o código está ficando tudo em uma única linha, preciso que ele fique identado ao ser gerado, respeitando a hierarquia. Não faço ideia como faz isso

Segue o código utilizado

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['create_xml'])){ echo "Programação das salas realizada";
/* All Links data from the form is now being stored in variables in string format */
$miro = $_POST['miro'];
$monet = $_POST['monet'];
$picasso = $_POST['picasso'];
$xmlBeg = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>";
$rootELementStart = "<reunioes>";
$rootElementEnd = "</reunioes>";
$xml_document= $xmlBeg;
$xml_document .= $rootELementStart;
$xml_document .= "<monet>";
$xml_document .= $monet; $xml_document .= "</monet>";
$xml_document .= "<picasso>";
$xml_document .= $picasso; $xml_document .= "</picasso>";
$xml_document .= "<miro>";
$xml_document .= $miro; $xml_document .= "</miro>"; 
$xml_document .= $rootElementEnd; 
$path_dir .= "reunioes" .".xml"; 

/* Data in Variables ready to be written to an XML file */ 
$fp = fopen($path_dir,'w'); 
$write = fwrite($fp,$xml_document); 
/* Loading the created XML file to check contents */ 
$sites = simplexml_load_file("$path_dir"); 
echo "<br> Checking the loaded file <br>" .$path_dir. "<br>"; 
?>
```

http://pastebin.com/Tq0kLDxk

Answer (score 5):

### XML Gerado manualmente

Não entendi bem a dificuldade, visto que é você mesmo quem está gerando o XML "manualmente". Basicamente, aplicar esta lógica em todas as linhas bastaria:

```
$xml_document .= "\t\t\t<monet>\n";
```

- Cada `\t` é um *tab*, insira a quantidade certa pra cada nível de indentação;
- O `\n` é a quebra de linha.

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/RSrHtQ)**.

### Solução geral com DOM

Agora, se precisar formatar um XML já pronto, pode usar a [DOM](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.dom.php).

```
$xml = '<root><foo><bar>baz</bar></foo></root>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = FALSE;
$dom->loadXML($xml);
$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
$formatado = $dom->saveXml();

echo $formatado;
```

Resultado:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <foo>
    <bar>baz</bar>
  </foo>
</root>
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/mJM2PH)**.

Comment: Sou iniciante, por isso a dificuldade, os tutoriais da net não me falaram sobre \t \n, muito obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @Leonardo dá uma lida em [tour] e veja que pode aceitar uma resposta que resolveu seu problema. Em breve poderá votar em tudo no site.